# Can't add to a Double type

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a double value I would like to increment, using the following snippet:

```
        Total = CDbl(Total + CDbl(Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value))
```

The code continuously returns a type mismatch error, even though the cell it points to has a decimal value in it.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know how you've defined Total, but just in case Total itself is the issue, try using CDbl(Total) inside the calculation as well. Otherwise, looks alright (depending on the actual value in that cell).

Comment: Total is dimenioned as a double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the cell you are pointing to actually contains a number, and not merely the number's text representation.

To convert a text cell to a number, select the cell, and then select Format/Cells from the menu bar, and then on the number tab, click General.

Comment: The cell is formatted as "Number," but for some reason was stored as a text field.  I fixed it manually.